# Get unique values from Eigen3 matrix

Tags: c++, eigen3

I've got a situation where I need to build a `std::set<int>` from the contents of an Eigen3 matrix. Let's call my matrix `ind`. I currently initialize my set like this:

```
std::set<int> q{ind.data(), ind.data() + ind.size()};
```

This works, but I'm wondering if there's an approach that isn't "going behind Eigen's back"?

Answer (score 1):

With the devel branch, you can write:

```
std::set<int> q{ind.begin(), ind.end()};
```

Comment: That's good to know! I may not be able to sell the rest of the team on switching to the devel branch, but I'll definitely try it myself.

Comment: Realistically, I'm not going to switch our project over to the devel branch, so I'm holding off on accepting this answer for the time being.